# How to handle with error "no such element: Unable to locate element" if on some pages selector is not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a simple script that grabs some data from a financial portal. It uses selenium/chromedriver to navigate and xpath to locate elements on webpage. Now i have a problem with structure of webpage because on some pages script is able to grab data from selectors and on some pages is not (data are not displayed/available). In such cases i receive error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

My qestion is: How can i handle with this error having knowledge that in some cases data are not available?

I tried to apply such code to solve this but script still is not able to to locate this element and rises above error.

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]').is_displayed():
    PE_current_list.append(PE_current.text)
else:
    PE_current_list.append('na')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `if-else` loop wrap up the logic in a `try/except{}` block catching `TimeoutException` as follows:

```
try:    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]"))):
    PE_current_list.append(PE_current.text)
except TimeoutException:
    PE_current_list.append('na')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a try/except where if it raises a `NoSuchElementException` you will append na to your list. Here an example:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    PE_current_list.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]').text)

except NoSuchElementException:
    PE_current_list.append('na')
```